# how to display form data for preview before submitting in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, forms

My View have a simple form. I want to show this data to user for review before submitting to the database. I am using Laravel 5.6

```
<form action="{{url('/posts')}}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="title">Title of your Post</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Post Title Goes here" name="title">     
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="body">Post Details</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="summernote"  placeholder="Detail of Post Goes here" name="body"></textarea>     
      </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
  </form>
```

I also want my user to edit it if he wants to make changes.

**Controller:**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //validate the form
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required',
            'body' => 'required'
        ]);

        //save data in database
        $data = $request->all();
        if(!empty ($data)){
            try{
                $newpost = new Post();
                $newpost->title = $data['title'];
                $newpost->body = $data['body'];
                $newpost->save();
                return redirect('/posts')->with('success', 'Record Added Successfuly');
            }catch(\Exception $e){
               // echo $e;
            }

        }//if ends here

    }
```

Comment: You have mainly to options, javascript approach or php approach, which one you prefer?

Comment: no specific requirement any approach would do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP approach

Use a confirmation URL, it can either be a get or a post, i rather use post

```php
Route::post('/posts/confirmation', 'PostController@confirmation');
```

Add this to your controller

```php
public function confirmation(Request $request)
{
    //validate the form
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required',
        'body' => 'required'
    ]);

    $data['myForm'] = $request->all();

    return view('posts.confirmation', $data)

}
```

Your confirmation view should look something like this:

```
<div>
   // your displaying view goes here
</div>
<form action="{{url('/posts')}}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <input type="hidden" name="title" value="{{ $myForm->title }}">     
    <textarea style="display:none;" name="body">{{ $myForm->body }}</textarea>     
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks @Erubiel. my question is if I use this approach then in this case will my form remains filled up with the fields **OR the user have to refill them again?**

Comment: Yeah, you just wont see it, since they are being passed to a hidden input and textarea.

Comment: It is working fine but I am confused why you have to use $data['myForm']? can't we access and display it without ['myForm'] piece of code?

Comment: Yes you could just pass the request item, but i don't know how would you access it. maybe check passing `view('posts.confirmation', $request)` and in the view check the defined vars to know what you should try to access using: `{{ dd(get_defined_vars()) }}`